# F# При делении суммы чисел в массиве на количество элементов ответ 0

Tags: деление, f#

Задание:
Сформировать список в диапазоне от -n до n согласно следующей закономерности: -n, n-1, -(n-2), n-3… Найти среднее арифметическое элементов списка.

Код на F#:

```
open System
let n = 20
let array = [| for i in 0 .. n -> if i%2=0 then ((n-i)* -1) else n-i |]
printfn "%A" array
array
    |> Array.sum
    |> printfn "Среднее арифметическое элементов списка: %A"
let ar = array
        |> Array.sum
        |> fun a -> a / 20
printfn "sum: %A" ar

//let ar2 = array |> Array.sum
//let ar3 = ar2
//let br = ar3 / n
//let br = ar 
//printfn "Среднее арифметическое элементов списка 2: %A" br
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Почему в итоге Среднее арифметическое равно нулю?
Если при дебагге правильно вычисляет и число n, и саму сумму элементов массива?

Comment: Возможно, вы используете целочисленное деление?

Comment: Проблема заключалась как раз таки в том, что делил int на int

Comment: Возможно вам будет интересно - недавно открыл [чат по F#](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f), поэтому если у вас возникнут какие - либо вопросы, то не стесняйтесь спрашивать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# делит int на int нацело. Приведите к float или double и получите 0.5:

```
let ar = array
        |> Array.sum
        |> float
        |> fun a -> a / 20.0
```

Или используйте оператор `/.` из набора [Type-inference friendly division and multiplication](http://www.fssnip.net/fy/title/Typeinference-friendly-division-and-multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

В `F#` для поиска среднего значения существует специальная функция [Array.average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.average%5b%5et%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d). Она имеет ограничение на использование только для элементов тех типов, которые поддерживают **DivideByInt**. Тип `int` к таким не относится, поэтому вы не можете использовать функцию.
Но вы можете использовать функцию [Array.averageBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.averageby%5b%27t%2c%5eu%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)

```
let avr = 
    array
    |> Array.averageBy float
```

---

В условии сказано:

> Сформировать список в диапазоне от -n до n согласно следующей закономерности:

Ваш код:

```
let array = [| for i in 0 .. n -> if i%2=0 then ((n-i)* -1) else n-i |]
```

задает только половину последовательности. Если вы хотите получить последовательность от [-n ; n], то вы можете использовать такой подход:

```
let array = 
    [| 
        for i in 0 .. 2 .. 2 * n - 1 do 
            yield -(n - i) 
            yield n - i - 1
        yield n
    |]
```

В таком случае среднее число элементов будет равно `0`, что достаточно очевидно.